# Call MySql function from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have created a function in MySQL :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`DBadmin`@`localhost` FUNCTION `insert_color`(
     p_color_Name VARCHAR(45)
) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        color_count INT;
    SELECT COUNT(p_color_Name) INTO color_count FROM Color
    WHERE p_color_Name = Color.Color_Name;

    IF color_count >= 1 THEN
        RETURN -1;
    ELSEIF color_count = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO Color(Color_Name)
        VALUES (p_color_Name);
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
END
```

And I want to call it in PHP to insert using the information that was typed in but I am having trouble.

```
<?php  

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','DBadmin','dbadmin','BirdDatabase');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
    echo "-1"; 
    return false; 
}  

$var1 = $_GET['selectedOption'];  
$var2 = $_GET['newNameText'];  
$var3 = $_GET['selectedType'];   

        else if ($var1 == "Color"){ 
            $sqlVariableUser = 'SELECT insert_color(?);';
            if(!$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlVariableUser)){
                exit($conn->error);
                return false;
            } else {
                $stmt->bind_param($var2);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result= $stmt->get_result();
                exit ($result);
            }
        } 
   ?>
```

Im new to MySQL, I know how to do this with an oracle database but I am having trouble with the MySQL connection. Any suggestions would be helpful :)

Comment: PHP code **makes no sense** does that code actually compile?? What does the code actually do or not do??

Comment: Does the function work if you use a straight SQL command? i.e. phpmyadmin, mysql workbench, etc?

Comment: I think you don't need a mysql function there either. Can be done using `INSERT...SELECT...WHERE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a lot of rigmarole to accomplish a fairly straightforward task. We tend to avoid creating MySQL stored programs when we can accomplish what we need with just SQL.

There's a potential race condition in the function, when it's executed simultaneously from two (or more) sessions. The SELECT in both executions may not find the specified `color_name`, and both sessions will then attempt to insert that same `color_name`.

If `color_name` should be UNIQUE in the color table, then declare a UNIQUE constraint, and let the database check it for you, and return an error when an attempt to insert a duplicate `color_name` into the table. Or, use `INSERT IGNORE` if you don't want to bother throwing the error. Or, an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement.

If there's some reason that `color_name` can't be made UNIQUE, you could still accomplish what that function is doing, using just one `INSERT ... SELECT` statement that performs a check if a row already exists.

```
INSERT INTO color (color_name) 
SELECT v.color_name
  FROM ( SELECT c.color_name 
           FROM ( SELECT ? AS color_name ) c
           LEFT
           JOIN color d
             ON d.color_name = c.color_name
          WHERE d.color_name IS NULL
            AND c.color_name IS NOT NULL
       ) v
```

Inline view `c` returns the a row containing the supplied value, the value of color_name we want to insert to the table, if a matching row doesn't already exist.

Inline view `v` uses an anti-join pattern, to return the row from `c` only if a matching row doesn't already exist in the table.  The outer `INSERT ... SELECT` will attempt to insert a row from `v`.

(You asked for suggestions; those are my suggestion.)